# Point vs MCvPoint2D64f, What is the difference between them?

Tags: c#, emgucv

I am coding in project that is using ConnectedCompnents method

My code:

```cs
temp = img.ThresholdBinary(new Gray(50), new Gray(255));
Mat label=new Mat();
Mat stats = new Mat();
Mat centroid = new Mat();


int nlabels = CvInvoke.ConnectedComponentsWithStats(temp, label, stats, centroid);
MCvPoint2D64f[] centerpoints = new MCvPoint2D64f[nlabels];
Point[] centerpoints2 = new Point[nlabels];
centroid.CopyTo(centerpoints);
centroid.CopyTo(centerpoints2);

foreach (MCvPoint2D64f pt in centerpoints)
{
    textBox1.AppendText($"x : {pt.X}  ,  y : {pt.Y}");
    CvInvoke.Circle(img, new Point((int)pt.X,(int)pt.Y), 10,new MCvScalar(0,0,255),3);
}

foreach (Point pt in centerpoints2)
{
    textBox2.AppendText($"x : {pt.X}  ,  y : {pt.Y}");
    CvInvoke.Circle(img2, new Point(pt.X, pt.Y), 10, new MCvScalar(0, 0, 255), 3);
}

imageBox2.Image = img;
imageBox1.Image = img2;
```

There are difference values in centroidPoints with `Point` and `MCvPoint2D64F` when this values shows in textboxes.

And with {Point}, circles did not drawn but with `MCvPoint2D64F` it is drawn correctly

What is difference between them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is that `MCvPoint2D64F` represents a point defined with `double` x / y coordinates whereas assuming a fairly standard set of using directives `Point` will be [System.Drawing.Point](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.point?view=netframework-4.8) that represents each point as a pair of integers. From the [CvInvoke.ConnectedComponentsWithStats](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.1.0/document/html/f1571e73-f897-c07b-de9a-1b474ac0442b.htm) documentation you'll see:

> centroids
>
> Type: Emgu.CV.IOutputArray
>
> Centroid output for each label, including the background label. Centroids are accessed via centroids(label, 0) for x and centroids(label, 1) for y. The data type CV_64F.

The 64F designator on the data type indicates a 64-bit floating point value which is a `double` in C# so you should be using `MCvPoint2D64F`. EmguCV won't attempt to translate values in an output array so when you're using `Point` it will copy the binary floating point representation into integers which won't make sense.